# Adding Multiple Action Items to Multiple Toolbars in Android

Tags: android, xml, user-interface, toolbar

So far, I have achieved the following:

[image: Multiple Toolbars Implementation Demonstration]

Im using **Appcompat Library** for customizing my Toolbars.

Files that are in use: 
a. **app_bar.xml** (top toolbar)
b. **app_bar_bottom.xml** (bottom toolbar)

my **main_menu.xml** looks like this:

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
tools:context=".MainActivity">
<item
    android:id="@+id/notices"
    android:orderInCategory="100"
    android:title="@string/notices"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_notices_white_24dp"
    app:showAsAction="never" />
<item
    android:id="@+id/exchange_rate"
    android:orderInCategory="100"
    android:title="@string/exchange_rate"
    app:showAsAction="always"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_rupees_white_24dp"/>
```

and at the **app_bar_bottom.xml** I have done something like this inside my **MainActivity.java** :

```
toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.app_bar_bottom);
    toolbar.setLogo(R.drawable.ic_rupees_white_24dp);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
```

The ic_rupees_white_24dp is an image file under drawable folder.

My question:

a. How can I add menu items to specific toolbars, i.e. different action items to top and bottom toolbar? Can it be achieved via xml declarations only without having to use `toolbar.setLogo()` and so forth?

b. Is there a way to assign each item declared inside **menu_main.xml** to be set to one particular toolbar only? For eg. the rupees image in the above screenshot is to be put as an action item at the bottom toolbar only?

Forgive me for my stupidity of the question is vague. It aroused only out of my curiosity.

Thank You.

Answer (score 0):

Within each toolbar, you should declare its ActionMenuView

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
    android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
    android:background="@color/light_primary_color"
    >
    <android.support.v7.widget.ActionMenuView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
    <android.support.v7.widget.ActionMenuView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        />
</android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
```